# Mover ficheros entre carpetas con caracteres especiales

Tags: windows, vbscript, vbs

Utilizo el siguiente script en vb para mover ficheros entre dos carpetas:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, objCarpetaOrigen, objArchivo, strCarpetaOrigen, strCarpetaDestino, strRutaDestino, objShell

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "chcp 65001", 0, True

strCarpetaOrigen = "\\SV1234\MINICOMPAÑÍA\2. Personas\8. Fichajes"
strCarpetaDestino = "G:\Test Eñe"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objCarpetaOrigen = objFSO.GetFolder(strCarpetaOrigen)

If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strCarpetaDestino) Then
    objFSO.CreateFolder(strCarpetaDestino)
End If


For Each objArchivo In objCarpetaOrigen.Files
    strRutaDestino = objFSO.BuildPath(strCarpetaDestino, objArchivo.Name)

    If Not objFSO.FileExists(strRutaDestino) Then
        objFSO.MoveFile objArchivo.Path, strCarpetaDestino            
    End If
Next
```

El problema es que si la carpeta tiene acentos o eñe me dice que la ruta no existe. En algunos sitios había leído que utilizando la línea "objShell.Run "chcp 65001", 0, True" se evitaba este problema pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Sigo sin encontrar solución. He tenido que hacerme un batch para copiar los ficheros porque con vbs no he sido capaz de momento.